# What's the difference between '' vs "" in build.gradle of Gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

Compare the:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6"
```

I used to use the `''` in my **build.gradle** because it's simpler than `""` and `("")`.

However I found the extra variables not work using `''`, for example,

Gradle is unable to resolve :

`compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$versions.commonsLang'`,

`compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$versions.commonsLang"` is
 working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'` (single quote) are used for standard java `String` whereas `"` (double quote) will be evaluated to `GString` if it has `$` expression or to plain `String` it it hasn't.

Since gradle scripts (in this particular case) are written in groovy have a look at the [docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#all-strings) also.

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed, `"` allows for [variable interpolation / expansion inside the string](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_string_interpolation), while `'` does not. It is considered good practive to use `'` if variable interpolation is not required, e.g. for performance reasons as the compiler does not need to parse the string for variable names then.

Comment: compiler performance?!

Comment: Well, parser, if you prefer. But yes, I like micro-optimizations :-D

Comment: I think even _"micro"_ is a couple of sizes too big...  what's below "nano-optimization"? ;-P